# How to fill table <td> with the background color of the checkbox <label>

Tags: html, css, checkbox

So I have this issue that' can't get over: the `<label>` when not checked is showing inside the `<td>` as a small red square in the middle, and what I need to do I need it to fill the whole `<td>` without specifing a size, since the `<td>` has a dynamic size.

**HTML**

```
<td class="checkbox_cell" ng-repeat="p1 in current_event.proposed"><input type="checkbox" class="toggle" ng-model="isChecked(p1)" ng-click="" name="thing" id="thing"><label for="thing"></td>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    background-color: #f7e9e8;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: url("../images/green_check.gif") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 2px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**

This has been solved simply by editing the "non-checked" css as follows:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: #BFE6BC url("../images/green_check.gif") center / 30px 30px no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

removing the `background-size: 100%` and adding `height: auto` and `min-height: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

you probably need something like that:

```
<td ng-class="{true: 'cell-is-selected', false: 'cell-isnt-selected'}[isChecked(p1)]">...</td>
```

and in your css:

```
.cell-is-selected { background: red; } .cell-isnt-selected { background: green }
```

Comment: so the logic works fine, in fact I didn't put angular in teh tags. Is the "non-checekd" option that I want the <td> to be all red.

Comment: You can't access to a parent via css, but you can easly do it via angular. Plus, you are using `id` attributes with the same value inside a loop, this generates invalid-html.

Comment: Yes you are right, but it's simply for posting the question and setting the checkbox styles

Answer (score 0):

In css , you'll find some tricky ways.

> Use a hudge box-shadow to fill entire parent area
>
> Move input ahead in the flow
>
> ...

examples

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  background-color: white;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background: url("../images/green_check.gif") no-repeat;
  background-color: red;
  border:solid 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 200px red;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 2px;
}
td {
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#thing2:checked + table .thing2 {
  background: lime;
}
h1 {
  font-size:1em;
  position: relative;
  /* to show on top of shadow of next elements */
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle" ng-model="isChecked(p1)" ng-click="" name="thing2" id="thing2">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="checkbox_cell" ng-repeat="p1 in current_event.proposed">
      <h1>label box-shadow</h1>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" ng-model="isChecked(p1)" ng-click="" name="thing" id="thing">
      <label for="thing">label</label>
      <p>blabla</p>
    </td>
    <td class="checkbox_cell thing2" ng-repeat="p1 in current_event.proposed">
      <h1>input outside front</h1>
      <label for="thing2">label</label>
      <p>blabla</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```